# Where to upload too big files?

Tags: discussion

I have a big HTML file that causes no errors in most of the browsers. However, when I open it with, let's say, Google Chrome, the program shuts down and I cannot trace why this is happening.

This HTML file is quite big and cannot be posted to a question in SO, but it should be ran as a whole as I cannot trace where the problem is. What is/are the most appropriate file upload website/s to upload and paste the link into the question?

Comment: I don't think such a question would be a good fit for SO at all. This is not a debugging service. See also [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Probably you should report the bug?

Comment: Your question deals with HTML in particular, and I think a concern is that you might be asking for help debugging an unreasonable amount of code when you should have reduced the problem to something more reasonable first. But it happens sometimes that questions deal with resources that are very large, like image or movie files, and which can't be posted on SO itself, so I the general question about large resources is a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is/are the most appropriate file upload website/s to upload and paste the link into the question?

**There's no established site for hosting content that can't be hosted on SO itself.** The main thing that matters from the point of a StackOverflow question is long-term validity, so try to put it somewhere that's stable enough that the page can stay there undisturbed for a long time. If your question relies on some resource that's too large to post on SO, put it somewhere else and provide a link to it.

**Don't expect folks here to dig through a huge volume of HTML to debug your problem.** If you think the problem is with some specific part of the file, it's up to you to do the work to narrow the problem down to something that you can reasonably post.

On the other hand, if the problem seems to be related merely to the size of the file and not to any specific code, I think that's a reasonable thing to ask about. In other words, if you can create a file that's filled with something inconsequential, like `<p>Hello world!</p>` repeated as many times as necessary to bulk up the file to the point where the problem occurs, then you have a reasonable question. (You also have a reasonable bug report, and should consider addressing the problem to the publisher of the browser rather than to SO.)

For example, a question like this should be okay:

> **Is there a standard HTML file size limitation?**
>
> I noticed that my browser fails to load files like this one
>   (`http://link/to/some/big/file`), but works with files that are similar and only
>   slightly smaller, like this one (`http://link/to/some/smaller/file`).
>   Have I discovered a problem with my browser, or is there some commonly
>   agreed upon limit to HTML file?

On the other hand, it would be poor form to ask something like this:

> **What's wrong with my HTML?**
>
> I've got an enormous HTML file here
>   (`http://link/to/some/buggy/html/file`) and I've been trying to debug
>   it for a week but I'm just really at a loss for what the problem could
>   be. Could someone maybe take a look and find the problem for me?

Answer (score 16):

Don't post the whole file, and **don't post a link to it!**

You should be able to narrow down the problem by following these steps:

1. Make a copy of the file
2. Remove some of the code
3. If problem is still there, go to step 2
4. Otherwise, undo deleting the code you deleted
5. The problem is the code you just undid! Post it.

Comment: What if it's the size of the HTML file and not its content that's the problem? I think there are some cases where posting a link to a large file is reasonable. What's not reasonable is expecting SO members to find the needle in your enormous haystack for you.

Answer (score 10):

People won't be interested in looking at a huge file that's part of a SO question. So you should create a minimal testcase reproducing the problem and post that one instead.

If you think you need to do it anyway: Put it on your webspace or some sane one-click-hoster (not full of ads, no annoying wait times) if you do not have webspace you can use. But only use that as a very last resort. As I said, people do not like looking at a wall of code.

Answer (score 6):

If it is too big to fit as plaintext on SO, then it is too large for the Q&A format. You should try to create a minimal example that triggers the error and post that in your question.

Creating a minimal example would also be the way many users would try to debug this problem, so it's a good idea anyway.

Comment: Why should file size be a discriminating factor? I agree that it'd be bad form to post a question asking people to debug several megabytes of HTML. But if it's simply a question where file size appears to be part of the problem, why is that not a valid question? In such a case, a minimal file might be several megabytes of `<p>Hello world!</p>`, i.e. large but not in question.