# What is the best place to upload files for use in questions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

Let's say I have a file, such as a HTML file or a Node project in a ZIP file. Where is the best place to upload this file when adding it to a question on Stack Overflow or another SE site?

Answer (score 7):

The problem with a post relying on an external site is they go down, links move, TOSes change, owners die...

As such it is always good to build *reasonably* scoped questions that don't rely on large amounts of external resources to both *understand* (so it may help others) and *answer*.

Answer (score -8):

From [Caleb](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172056/744107):

> There's no established site for hosting content that can't be hosted on SO itself. The main thing that matters from the point of a StackOverflow question is long-term validity, so try to put it somewhere that's stable enough that the page can stay there undisturbed for a long time. If your question relies on some resource that's too large to post on SO, put it somewhere else and provide a link to it.

Some recommendations are:

- [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com)
- [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com)
- [Dropbox](https://dropbox.com)
- [GitHub](https://github.com) (for large projects)
- [CodePen](https://codepen.io) (Front-End programs using e.g. JavaScript)
- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) (Back-End programs using e.g. Node.js, React.js)
- [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com) (for 1 file)
- Host the file yourself on a development environment (such as `development.example.com/myproject.zip`)